# phpmyadmin stored pocedure syntax error sum(convert (field,decimal(4,2)))

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The following stored procedure is showing #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(CONVERT(hoursworked.starhours, DECIMAL(4,2))) FROM hoursworked WHERE h' at line 18. (The line that starts SET vhours =.

If I substitute the variables for values and run as an sql query it workd fine.

I am unable to find any syntax error and would be much obliged if anyone could point me in the right direction.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE set_monw()
BEGIN

DECLARE vmonw, vmona, vmonb, vtuew, vtuea, vtueb, vwedw, vweda, vwedb, vthuw, vthua, vthub, vfriw, vfria, vfrib, vsatw, vsata, vsatb, vsunw, vsuna,
vsunb, vowork, vwwt, vwat, vwbt, vrwt, vavg, smonb, stuew, stuea, stueb, swedw, sweda, swedb, sthuw, sthua, sthub, sfriw, sfria, sfrib, ssatw,
ssata, ssatb, ssunw, ssuna, ssunb, sowork, nwwt, nwat, nwbt, nrwt, navg, vhours, vmins, vrawmins DECIMAL(4,2);

DECLARE vempid, vwkno INT;

DECLARE vweekend DATE;  

DECLARE rtddata CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM rtd;

OPEN rtddata;

mainloop:

LOOP

FETCH rtddata INTO vempid, vwkno, vweekend, vmonw, vmona, vmonb, vtuew, vtuea, vtueb, vwedw, vweda, vwedb, vthuw, vthua, vthub, vfriw, vfria, vfrib, vsatw, vsata, vsatb, vsunw, vsuna, vsunb, vowork, vwwt, vwat, vwbt, vrwt, vavg;

SET vhours = SELECT SUM(CONVERT(hoursworked.starthrs, DECIMAL(4,2))) FROM hoursworked WHERE hoursworked.empid = vempid
                AND hoursworked.wkno = vwkno AND hoursworked.company = 'Hrs Worked (inc driving)' AND hoursworked.day = 1 GROUP BY
                hoursworked.empid, hoursworked.wkno, hoursworked.company, hoursworked.day;

SET vrawmins = SELECT SUM(CONVERT(hoursworked.startmins, DECIMAL(4,2))) FROM hoursworked WHERE hoursworked.empid = vempid
                AND hoursworked.wkno = vwkno AND hoursworked.company = 'Hrs Worked (inc driving)' AND hoursworked.day = 1 GROUP BY
                hoursworked.empid, hoursworked.wkno, hoursworked.company, hoursworked.day;

SET vhours = vhours + (vrawmins/60);

UPDATE rtd SET rtd.monw = vhours WHERE rtd.empid = vempid AND rtd.wkno = vwkno;

END LOOP;

CLOSE rtddata;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Sorry but I found the answer myself.  It needed parenthesis around the select statement.

Eddie L